# Display all values using a CSV column as condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, pdo

I have a query that supposed to display a page's name where a particular user has accessed to. The users table has a column that has a CSV of page ids that the user has accessed to.
The page's names is located in another table with corresponding page ids.

Here is the structure of the 2 tables

```html
+------------+---------------------+
| User Table |                     |
+------------+---------------------+
| USERID     | PAGE                |
| john01     | 101,102,            |
| chris5     | 101,001,003,004,005 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

```html
+------------+------------------+
| PAGE TABLE |                  |
+------------+------------------+
| PAGEID     | PAGENAME         |
| 101        | Account settings |
| 102        | Details          |
| 001        | Setup account    |
| 002        | Profile          |
| 003        | Reset Password   |
| 004        | Edit user        |
| 005        | Manage accounts  |
+------------+------------------+
```

My problem is how can I display all page names accessible to a particular user like:

> john01

My query is:

```
select pagename as Pages
from 
Page
where 
pageid in (select page from user where userid = 'john01')
```

This query only displays one pagename but not 2 pagenames as indicated on the table structure.

How can I retreive all pages for a particular user using this 2 table structure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best structure to go, but I believe you can manage it using this query:
( I would however strongly recommend to normalize the user page table to make a single page id per record reference.)

`SELECT p.pagename FROM Pages p, User u WHERE u.userid = "john01" AND u.PAGE LIKE "%p.PAGEID%"`

**EDIT:**
I started PhpMyAdmin to recreate the query, however since I believe it's not in my nature to write a query like this.

I would recommend you to normalize your table structure like this:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`page`(`
id`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
name`varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`user`(`
id`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
name`varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`userpages`(`
userid`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`
pageid`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`pageid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Now the page table lists all available pages. the user table just list usernames to user id's. and the magic happens in the userpages table. where you make relevant references (rights?) between pages and users.

You can now query the pages using the following SQL query:
`SELECT p.id, p.name FROM page p, user u, userpages up WHERE u.name = 'john01' and u.id = up.userid AND up.pageid = p.id`